# parameter is coming out undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am in the process of building a hangman game. In my checkLetter function is where i am going to write code to check if a letter matches a chosen word. However I have noticed that when i passed in letter to onclick for function checkLetter, the console log will come out undefined but it will also display collection of html tags from the button that is pressed. In the function checkLetter i passed in pickLetter as a parameter. This is where buttons work but it also comes out undefined. I am very certain that I wrote this correctly but i know something is missing. Any help? I hope i made myself clear.

```
document.body.onload = createButtons;
//keyboard added dynamically
function createButtons() {
    const buttons = alphabet.map(letter =>
        `<button id = "${letter}" 
        class="btn btn-primary letterKey" 
        button type="button" 
        value="${letter}" 
        onclick = "checkLetter(${letter})"
        >
        ${letter}
        </button>`).join('');
    keyboardBtn.innerHTML = buttons;

    //prints letters to answer input/screen
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("letterKey"))
        .forEach((e) =>
            e.addEventListener("click", () => placeLetters.innerHTML += e.value))
}

//check letter of chosen word, if its there or not
function checkLetter(pickLetter) {
    console.log(pickLetter)

}
checkLetter();






<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
        <title>Hangman 2021</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <!--header-->
        <header class="container-fluid bg-success text-dark">
            <div>
                <span>
                    <h1 class="text-center">Hang that man</h1>
                </span>
            </div>
        </header>
        
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <h3>Please choose a letter on your keyboard to reaveal the secret word</h3>
            <br>
            <!--each letter will display after all lives are gone-->
            <div id="keyboard"></div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <!--choices will be inserted here-->
            <div id="answer-input">
                <p id="letter-input">_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ </p>
            </div>
            
            <!--number of lives will be tracked here-->
            <p id="lives">You have 8 lives left</p>
            
            <!--everytime a guess is wrong, a limb is added to animation-->
            <section class="animation">
                <div class="justify-content-center">
                    <canvas id="gallows" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3"></canvas>
                </div>
                <button id="reset">Play Again</button>
            </section>
            <br>
        </div>
        
        <!--footer-->
        <footer class="container-fluid bg-success text-dark">
            <div class="justify-content-center">Hang that man © 2021</div>
            <div class="social justify-content-center">
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/andres-ramirez12/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                &nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://github.com/ARam2142" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="github">
                <a>Andres Ramirez</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
        
        <script type="text/javascript"src="index.js" defer></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more what the problem is exactly? Perhaps provide the HTML as well in a snippet that we can run? Note that your initial `checkLetter()` call will log `undefined`, I'm not sure why that's there - but the `onclick`, at a glance, shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using :

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("letterKey"))
        .forEach((e) =>
            e.addEventListener("click", () => placeLetters.innerText+= e.value))
```

(note that innerHtml returns everything from html) you could try:

- placeLetters.textContent
- placeLetters.innerText
- placeLetters.value

Answer (score 0):

I created an example with comments. You can use it to see how to handle the clicks. I would advise to use event delegation to handle click events instead of 26 separate handlers. [See this blog for more info](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate#:%7E:text=Event%20delegation%20allows%20you%20to,just%20how%20event%20delegation%20works.). I added comments to the code below so it's pretty clear but let me know if you have any questions. The game obviously isn't 100% finished, but should be enough so you can take it from there.

```js
//Your HTML elements that will be used for the game UI
const btnContainerEl = document.querySelector("#btn-container");
const guessTrackerEl = document.querySelector("#guess-tracker");
const winningWordEl = document.querySelector("#winning-word");

//Some const variables to avoid magic numbers in the code
const CHAR_CODE_a = 97;
const STRIKES_TIL_HANGED = 5;

//A variable to keep track of the remaining letters the player needs to win
let lettersNeededToWin;

//A variable to keep track of unsuccessful guesses
let strikes = 0;

initGame();

function initGame() {
  getWinningWord();
  createLetterButtons();
}

function getWinningWord() {
  //Get the winning word from a prompt and create an array of it's letters
  lettersNeededToWin = window.prompt("Enter winning word").toLowerCase().split('').sort();
}

function createLetterButtons() {
  //Loop 26 times to create a button for each letter in the English alphabet
  for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    const char = String.fromCharCode(CHAR_CODE_a + i);
    const btnText = document.createTextNode(char);
    const buttonEl = document.createElement("BUTTON");

    buttonEl.appendChild(btnText);
    //Append the button the UI
    btnContainerEl.appendChild(buttonEl);
  }

  //Add a click event to the parent container instead of each individual button.
  btnContainerEl.addEventListener('click', handleLetterButtonClick);
  //1 event handler is more efficient than 26 seperate handlers.
}

function handleLetterButtonClick(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName != "BUTTON") {
    return;
  }

  e.target.disabled = true;
  updateGuessTracker(e.target.textContent);
  if (lettersNeededToWin.includes(e.target.textContent)) {
    while (lettersNeededToWin.includes(e.target.textContent)) {
      //Remove these letters from the array (in-place operation)
      lettersNeededToWin.splice(lettersNeededToWin.indexOf(e.target.textContent), 1);
    }
  } else {
    //Add another strike since players guess was incorrect
    strikes++;
  }

  //Check the number of letters left and number of strikes to determine win/lose outcome
  if (lettersNeededToWin.length == 0) {
    console.log("YOU WIN!");
  } else if (strikes == STRIKES_TIL_HANGED) {
    console.log("YOU LOSE!");
  }
}

function updateGuessTracker(guessLetter) {
  guessTrackerEl.innerHTML += `<font color="${lettersNeededToWin.includes(guessLetter) ? 'green' : 'red'}">${guessLetter}</font>&nbsp;`;
}
```

```html
<div id="winning-word">Winning word:</div>
<br/>
<div id="btn-container"></div>
<div id="guess-tracker">Guessed letters:</div>
```